# How create a htmleditor in qooxdoo as desktop

Tags: desktop, qooxdoo, html-editor

I'd like to create a window with a HtmlEditor 
like as:

```
var be= new qx.ui.form.TextArea("");
be.setWrap(true);

var htm= new qx.bom.htmlarea.HtmlArea(be,"test");
this.add(htm);
```

I get a error:

```
TypeError: parent is null
if (parent.firstChild) {
```

Many Thanks

Mani

Answer (score 1):

You can not add a qooxdoo Object into the HtmlArea.

The first parameter is expected to be a HTML Element:

> http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.bom.htmlarea.HtmlArea

Have a quick look at this demo (especially the JS Code):

> http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/demobrowser/#bom~HtmlArea.html

Comment: But it is possible to create a htmlarea in Qooxdoo Desktop?? I'd like create a window with a HtmlArea. Thank you...